# Spring HAL link destinations

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

Using Spring Boot, I get unexpected links for entities having other entities as field. Condensed example:

```
@Entity Foo { ... }

interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository<Foo, Long> ...

@Entity Bar {
    @ManyToOne
    Foo foo;
    ...
}

interface BarRepository extends CrudRepository<Bar, Long> ...
```

When GET'ting a `Bar` entity, the response contains the following links:

```
{
  ...
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:9001/bars/1"
    },
    "bar": {
      "href": "http://localhost:9001/bars/1"
    },
    "foo": {
      "href": "http://localhost:9001/bars/1/foo"
    }
  }
}
```

For the "foo" link, I'd have expected to get the URI of the `Foo` entity as link, that is `<host>/foo/<id>` instead of `<host>/bars/1/foo`. Both links deliver exactly the same response. The examples in the HAL spec show the expected behavior, and I also find it much more useful, for example if I want to do caching in the client. Having different URIs for the same resource does not seem helpful.

What is the reasoning behind this behavior? Can anyone point me to the relevant docs?

Comment: 5.4. The association resource.

Comment: @zeroflagL so how would I use the `@RestResource` annotation to change the behavior? The `path` and `rel` properties change the name of the resource, but that's all I've been able to accomplish.

Comment: I don't think you can change that behavior. The reason the URI exists is that you can also POST / PUT to it and thereby change the referenced `foo` instance. You can always add a `ResourceProcessor` that adds another link, one pointing "directly" to the `Foo` entity. See 16.5.1

Comment: @zeroflagL I can follow that reasoning, even though the behavior is a bit at odds with my feeling how REST should behave. If you put it up as an answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: Please, keep in mind that REST is only an architectural style that defines constraints. How it is applied / implemented is up to the developer. Your preferred solution and Spring one's have different goals, but neither of them violates REST principles.